# Prolog concatenation confusion

Tags: prolog

Okay so I've got some code which concatenates two lists. There's no problem with the code at all, rather, just me struggling to understand how it works.

- I understand this will be trivial to the most of you.

Here is the code:

```
conc([],L,L).
conc([H|L1],L2,[H|L3]):-
     conc(L1,L2,L3).
```

Say we have 2 lists: [3, 4, 2] and [9, 9] that I would like to concatenate.

```
Step 1: 
H = 3 
L2 = [9, 9] 
L1 = 4,2

Step 2:
L2  = [9, 9]
H   = 4
L1  = [2]

Step 3:
L2  = [9, 9]
H   = 2
L1  = []

Step 4:
L = [9,9] .... Now why does it not just fail? In my brain [9,9] is not equal to [3, 4, 2]

Step 5:

L2 = L3 = [9, 9]
H   = 2
L1  = []


Step 6:

L2  = [9, 9]
H   = 4
L1  = [2]
L3  = [2, 9, 9]

Step 7:

L2  = [9, 9]
H   = 3
L1  = [4, 2]
L3  = [4, 2, 9, 9]    And done
```

What am I finding so confusing? I must be looking at this wrong, also L2 just stays static throughout the recursive calls so I don't understand what we've achieved from moving the first input to the third?

Comment: Step 4 doesn't fail because you are unifying `conc([], L, L)` with `conc([], [9, 9], L)` which simply yields `L = [9, 9]`. Why do you think that would fail? `[3, 4, 2]` doesn't even appear anywhere in this unification step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your step 4, you are not unifying `[3, 4, 2]` and `[9, 9]`; you are unifying `[9, 9]` with a free variable.

You are correct that the bindings in step 3 are `L2 = [9, 9]`, `H = 2`, and `L1  = []`. Note that `L3` is unbound! The recursive call is `conc(L1, L2, L3)`, so `conc([], [9, 9], L3)`. This goal will unify with the first clause of `conc`, introducing the new binding `L3 = [9, 9]`. This is due to the clause `conc([], L, L)`, which forces `L3` to be unified with whatever `L` is bound to, which in this call is just `[9, 9]`.

Then evaluation proceeds with your step 5 as you describe.

Your Prolog might have a tracer that helps you understand this. In SWI-Prolog tracing a `conc` goal looks like this (the `_Gxxxx` are free variables):

```
?- trace, conc([a,b], [c,d], Xs).
   Call: (7) conc([a, b], [c, d], _G2467) ? creep
   Call: (8) conc([b], [c, d], _G2590) ? creep
   Call: (9) conc([], [c, d], _G2593) ? creep
   Exit: (9) conc([], [c, d], [c, d]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) conc([b], [c, d], [b, c, d]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) conc([a, b], [c, d], [a, b, c, d]) ? creep
Xs = [a, b, c, d].
```

Note that the third `Call` is entered with a variable as the third argument and `Exit`s with that variable bound to a list.